# Coordinates of vectors in bases

Tags: vector-spaces

Two vectors from the standard basis are $a = (1,0,1)$ and $b = (1,1,1)$. What are the coordinates of these vectors in the basis $\{(1,2,3),(2,3,1),(3,0,1)\}$.

I am not even sure how to answer this question. I have tried looking up how to find coordinates for vectors in basis and I haven't found anything useful yet. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Write (1, 0, 1) = a(1, 2, 3)+b(2, 3, 1) + c(3, 0, 1) then find a, b, c and you are done.

Comment: @Paul, only half-done, as there's still $b$ to do (by the same method, of course).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a matrix with the columns being the vectors given in the basis (to understand where this matrix comes from, see Paul's comment):

$$A=
\left[ \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 2 & 3 \\
2 & 3 & 0 \\
3 & 1 & 1 \end{array} \right] $$

This is a transformation matrix and can be used to change the basis of a vector (which is essentially a linear transformation). So if we're given a vector $\vec{x}$ from the non-standard basis, we have;

$$\vec{y}=A\vec{x}$$

where $\vec{y}$ is the vector constructed from the standard basis. In this particular problem, we're given the vectors from the standard basis, so we need the inverse of the transformation matrix. Simply find $A^{-1}\vec{a}$ and $A^{-1}\vec{b}$, and the elements of the resulting vectors correspond to the coordinates of the vectors $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$ in the non-standard basis.